# React Bootstrap: set props on component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Due to a rather elaborate scenario I won't explain, I need to be able to set the `placement` prop on a React Bootstrap component dynamically when the user initiates the trigger. I was thinking something like this:

```
<OverlayTrigger
    ref="trigger"
    onEnter={onEnterFunc}
    placement="bottom"
    overlay={<Popover>...</Popover>}>
   <span>html</span>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Then in onEnterFunc somehow dynamically change the placement value. Anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the current value of `placement` in a parent component's state. You can specify an initial value in the component's constructor, and you can update this value by calling `setState` in your `onEnterFunc` function. Your updated markup/render function will look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
       <OverlayTrigger
           ref="trigger"
           onEnter={() => this.onEnterFunc()}
           placement={this.state.placement}
           overlay={<Popover>...</Popover>}>
           <span>html</span>
        </OverlayTrigger>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yegads. Totally missed that. Appreciated! Works like a charm. :D